# Чтение struct в queue

Tags: c++, stl, очередь

Добрый день! Задача следующая,  реализовать запись и чтение в очередь... С записью вопросов не возникает.

```
//создаем необходимую структуру
struct my_data_rows 
{
    char* name1;
    char* name2;
    char* name3;
    char* name4;
};
//объявляем очередь
queue<my_data_rows> queue_rows_with_data;
//записываем
bool writeDataToBuffer(char* name1, char* name2, char* name3, char* name4) {
    my_data_rows new_my_data;
    new_my_data.name1 = name1;
    new_my_data.name2 = name2;
    new_my_data.name3 = name3;
    new_my_data.name4 = name4;
    queue_rows_with_data.push(new_my_data);
    return true;
}
```

С этим вроде бы все понятно. Вот не понятно начинается дальше, когда я пытаюсь прочитать из очереди..

```
bool readDataToBuffer() 
{
    my_data_rows new_my_data;
    for (int x = 0; x < queue_rows_with_data.size(); x++) 
      {
        queue_rows_with_data.pop();
      }
    return true;
}
```

Собственно сам вопрос, как прочитать из очереди структуру, и вывести например с помощью стандартного оператора cout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас спасет `front()` - в силу ряда проблем с безопасностью исключений функция, возвращающая элемент, и функция, удаляющая его - это разные функции.

```
bool readDataToBuffer() 
{
    my_data_rows new_my_data;
    while(!queue_rows_with_data.empty())
    {
        new_my_data = queue_rows_with_data.front();
        cout << new_my_data.name1 << endl;
        queue_rows_with_data.pop();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Вопрос только - вы собираетесь хранить в структуре именно указатели? Так, чисто на всякий случай - надеюсь, вы отдаете себе отчет, что данные, на которые они указывают, должны быть актуальны при работе с ними (что вы там собираетесь делать - выводить?)

Comment: Действительно, заменил указатели типа char на переменные string. Еще вопрос, я изначально занес в очередь 1000 элементов типа struct, после, считал все из очереди предложенным вами способом. Как высвободить правильно память, очистить контейнер и уменьшить занимаемую им память? В deque, например, есть удобная функция shrink_to_fit() для высвобождении неиспользуемой памяти. Насколько мне известно до этой функции использовалось что то вроде: 
   
 `queue<my_data_rows> queue_rows_with_data_new;
  queue_rows_with_data.swap(queue_rows_with_data_new);`

насколько это эффективно?

Comment: Ну, вроде бы должно сработать... Но в принципе, 1000 элементов - это не так уж много, чтоб из-за этого заморачиваться. Но я что-то не помню, в деках же вроде немного другая технология, основанная на блоках - там по логике блоки должны освобождаться автоматически?

Comment: Ну автоматически после вызова функции. В деках удобно что есть функция clear(не запариваясь можно очистить весь контейнер целиком), а потом  shrink_to_fit(), и ваша память снова свободна. 
Пример который я выше привел, это из Саттера, им пользовались(полагаю пользуются) до с++11. Мне интересно как раз именно современные методы(если они появились).

Comment: Полез в стандарт. Способа достучаться до контейнера там нет (разве что он - `protected`, так что можно наследовать очередь и работать с контейнером), но `swap` вроде бы должен отработать...